# accessing global variable inside javascript nested function

Tags: plugins

I want to access global variable inside javascript nested function and append some value inside the nested function and display that variable out side the nested function with the value appended in nestedfunction

eg:

```
function a()
{
 var res="";
  function b()
   {
     res=res+"hello"; 
      alert(res);    //alert dialog with hello is appearing
   }
   alert(res);      //empty alert dialog is appearing,but I want this alert to
                     display hello,means "res" must act as global variable.  
}
```

can you please give the solution for this.....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code is complete mess. Try this:

```
var res="A";
b();
alert(res);  
function b()
{
  res=res+"hello"; 
  alert(res);    
};
```